# Construct a logic diagram that computes pi using the Adamchick series

Tags: python, for-loop, logic, diagram

Construct a logic diagram that computes pi using the Adamchick series shown below. The logic should evaluate the series to an arbitrary number of terms N. Implement the logic using a for-loop in Python and submit a program adamchick.py.
[Adamchick series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SQfE.png)

Comment: where is series?

Comment: Adamchick series shown below.? where?

Comment: It would not allow me to put it in. However, I got the answer. N=int(input("Enter a number for N: "))
X=float(input("Enter a number for X: "))
pi=o
for X in range (0,N):
________pi += ((4/(8*X+1))-(2/(8*X+4))-(1/(8*X+5))-(1/(8*X+6)))*((1/16)**X)
print(pi)

Comment: who stops you to put in in?

Comment: I didn't know how to share pictures